# Create web link in a pargraph

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to add a link as a hyperlink in a paragraph when paragraph comes from Json as a string,

```
<p>Dumy Dumy Dumy Dumy Dumy Dumy Dumy DumyDumyDumyDumy  abc.com </p>
```

this display as it is, but i want to display abc.com as hyperlink or web link

Comment: I'm fetched data from JSON file which have text data and included links, Now i want to display these link as weblink or hyperlink. how can i do that. I.m searching for a approach best fit for angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to split your data model into 2 parts... text and hyperlink text. Then you can specifically set a hyperlink in your template. eg.

JSON model:

```
{
  data: {
    description: 'dummy text',
    link: 'http://www.example.com',
    linkText: 'abc.com'
  }
}
```

From there your HTML template could look like...

```
<p>
  {{ data.description }}
  <a href="{{ data.link }}">{{ data.linkText }}</a>
</p>
```

Angular has measures in place to protect you from injecting HTML into your template. Though you can bypass this with the `$sce` service. Though I would strongly advise you rethink your design prior to using this unless it is absolutely necessary. For more information you can read up on: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml